# UILongPressGestureRecognizer doesn't work properly

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, uigesturerecognizer

I want to make right side of the screen to make the node jump, first half of the left part to left and second half to move right.

Some stuff that aren't okay:

- when I tap fast left,right,left,right many times (it will stop and will not move the node)
- when I tap the right part of the screen And tap of the left or right section not every time the node moves when is falling, some times the first problem will repeat

Here is an example of game with the same mechanics:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/staying-together/id923670329?mt=8

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */
    let tapper = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tappedScreen:");
    tapper.minimumPressDuration = 0.1
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapper)
}

func jumpAction(){
    if(!isJumping){
        hero.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: ySpeed))
    }   
    isJumping = true
}

func tappedScreen(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began){     
        let moveLeft = SKAction.moveByX(-15, y: 0, duration: 0.1)
        let moveRight = SKAction.moveByX(15, y: 0, duration: 0.1)

        let touchY = self.convertPointFromView(recognizer.locationInView(self.view)).y

        // only the bottom part of the screen, that way the UI button will be able to touch
        if(touchY < self.frame.size.height/4){      
            if(touchX > 0){
                println("up - longer");
            } else if(touchX < -(self.frame.size.width/4)){      
                println("left - longer");
                hero.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveLeft), withKey: "longTap")
            } else {
                println("right - longer");
                hero.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveRight), withKey: "longTap")
            }
        } 
    } else {
        if(touchX <= 0){
            if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended) {
                println("ended, also stops the node from moving");
                hero.removeActionForKey("longTap")
            }
        }
    }
}

// I think this is need to mmove the node on single tap
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    let touch: UITouch = touches.first as! UITouch;
    let location:CGPoint = touch.locationInNode(self);

    let moveLeft = SKAction.moveByX(-15, y: 0, duration: 0.1)
    let moveRight = SKAction.moveByX(15, y: 0, duration: 0.1)

    // only the bottom part of the screen, that way the UI button will be able to touch
    if(location.y < self.frame.size.height/4){
        if(location.x > 0){
            println("up");
            self.jumpAction();
        } else if(location.x < -(self.frame.size.width/4)){
            hero.runAction(moveLeft);
            println("left");
        } else {
            hero.runAction(moveRight);
            println("right");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because tappedScreen has an argument that refers to UITapGestureRecognizer. you have to set it to UILongPressGestureRecognizer.

func tappedScreen(recognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){

}

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I make the change you suggested but still the problem persist

Comment: you said UILongPressGestureRecognizer doesn't work properly.

Comment: and why do you even use uilongpress for tapping? just use tap. the 0.1 thingy is not good because a tap is shorter than 0.1 secs

Comment: yes, if play the game the hero move on tap, and also on long press! Another game is Run Bird Run by ketchapp

Comment: Right now I press the to move right, then I release fast and press to move left, but it freeze, and the last log is "ended, also stops the node from moving" UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended. Move to left part is not triggered

Comment: 0.1 secs may sometimes conflict with a tap. try making it longer than that, something like 0.3 secs.